# Webpack. Created library with dependencies is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I try to create react library with Webpack.

Simplified structure of library:

```
+ Base
|
|--- index.js

export * from "./Base";

|--- Base.jsx

export const Base = { "base_property_1": "base_property_1_value" };

+ Data
|
|--- index.js

export * from "./Data";

|--- Data.jsx

import { Base } from "../Base";

export const Data = { "data_property_1": "data_property_1_value", ...Base };

+ Red
|
|--- index.js

export * from "./Red";

|--- Red.jsx

import React from "react";

export const Red = () => <div>[Red]</div>;
```

I try to build library with this webpack.library_create.config.js:

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        "Base": path.resolve(__dirname, "./library_src/Base"),
        "Data": path.resolve(__dirname, "./library_src/Data"),
        "Red": path.resolve(__dirname, "./library_src/Red"),
    },
    externals: {
        "react": "commonjs react",
        "react-dom": "commonjs react-dom",
    },    
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ["babel-loader"],
            },
        ],
    },
    optimization: {
        minimize: false,
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: "all",
            minChunks: 2,
            minSize: 1,
        },
    },
    output: {
        clean: true,
        filename: "[name]/index.js",
        libraryTarget: "umd",
        library: "Astra",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./node_modules/@a/library"),
        umdNamedDefine: true,
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx"],
    },
    target: "web",
};
```

Then I try to start project:

```
+ dist
|--- index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div></div>
        <script src="./bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>


+ library_use
|--- index.jsx

import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Data } from "@a/library/Data";
import { Red } from "@a/library/Red";

console.log(Data);

const App = () => <div>App <Red /></div>;

ReactDOM.render( <App />, document.querySelectorAll( "body > div" )[ 0 ] );
```

using webpack.library_use.config.js:

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "./library_use/index.jsx"),
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ["babel-loader"],
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx"],
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist"),
        filename: "bundle.js",
    },
    plugins: [ new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin() ],
    devServer: {
        hot: true,
        open: true,
        port: 3020,
        static: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist"),
            {
                directory: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist"),
                serveIndex: true,
                watch: true,
            },
        ],        
    },
};
```

And I getting error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Data')

i.e. Data is not initialized.

If I remove dependency Base from Data, then Data initialized:

```
+ Data
|--- Data.js

// import { Base } from "../Base";

// export const Data = { "data_property_1": "data_property_1_value", ...Base };
export const Data = { "data_property_1": "data_property_1_value", };
```

**How to set up webpack.library_create.config.js to build my library with dependencies to work my project (with webpack.library_use.config.js)?**

This project on git https://github.com/rosinfotech/issue_210921_webpack_library_dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, nobody answered my issue. Even collaborators of the Webpack projects define the issue as discussion and suppose to figure out in Webpack code to resolve this problem myself https://github.com/webpack/webpack/discussions/14303#discussioncomment-1376696 But I chosen another way – the Rollup, which resolved my task very effectively https://github.com/rosinfotech/issue_210921_webpack_library_dependencies/tree/rollup

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).